# Как прервать axios запрос

Tags: vue.js, axios

Нужно чтобы при получении запроса предыдущий такой же запрос прерывался.Можете посмотреть данный кусок кода и подсказать что не так, что нужно исправить? Буду очень благодарна. Использовала AbortController и CancelToken вместе.

```
 getUsers ({
          commit
        }, { search }) {
          const controller = new AbortController()
          const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken
          const source = CancelToken.source()
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('preloaderStatus')
            axios({
              url: apiUrl + `/api/users?search=${search}`,
              method: 'GET',
              cancelToken: source.token,
              signal: controller.signal
            })
              .then(resp => {
                commit('preloaderStatus')
                resolve(resp)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                commit('preloaderStatus')
                reject(err)
              })
           source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.')
           controller.abort()
          })
        }
```

Дело в том что у меня  данные совсем перестали грузиться. Нужно ли условие добавить? но в других примерах такого не вижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, что я правильно разобрался:
Вы параллельно отправляете запрос и сразу же его отменяете.
И к моменту отправки уже стоит флаг отмены запроса, запрос даже никуда не уходит.

Но в консоли можно увидеть ошибку через блок `catch`.

Что можно сделать:

1. засуньте отмену запроса в функцию или создайте условие, по которому будет происходить отмена запроса.
2. в инструментах разработчика, в разделе "Сеть" задайте минимальную скорость подключения - у меня в fire fox это GPRS.
   При таких условиях запрос будет отправляться достаточно долго, чтоб увидеть его в разделе сеть в консоли разработчика и отменить.
   Код ниже работает.

   ```
   http
     .get('', {
       signal: controller.signal,
     })
     .then((resp) => {
       store.setCharacters(resp.data)
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
     })
   setTimeout(() => {
     controller.abort()
   }, 10)
   ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]